# Return true if all values of one smaller dictionary exist in a larger dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, compare, key

How do I get a return of True if all, *and just not any*, values of Key1 in A exist in B, without B having the exact amount of values?

I have one dictionary (A) with multiple smaller keys, and another dictionary (B) with only one key but with more values:

```
A = {'Key1': ['ONE', 'THREE', 'TWO', 'EIGHT', 'ONE-HUNDRED'],
     'Key2': ['THREE', 'EIGHT', 'FORTYSEVEN', 'TWO'],
     'Key3': ['ONE-HUNDRED', 'SEVEN', 'NINE', 'ONE']
    }

B = {'Key1': ['TWENTY', 'SIXTYEIGHT', 'ONE-HUNDRED', 'SEVEN', 
     'FIVE', 'NINE', 'ONE', 'ZERO', 'ELEVEN', 'TWO-HUNDRED',
     'TWENTY-EIGHT', 'FOUR', 'TWELVE']
}
```

I have tried with both set() and all(). I use this to get the corresponding key (Key1 in this case):

```
match = [k for k in B if B[k] != A[k]]
for k in match:
    print k

>>> 'Key1'
```

I guess I could use `matched = True/False` in a for loop. I am using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do use sets; test if the set of `A['Key1']` is smaller or equal to the set in `B`:

```
set(A['Key1']) <= set(B['Key1'])
```

`<=` is only true if *all* elements of the set on the left are also in the set on the right, where the set on the right is allowed to have more elements:

```
>>> setb = set(['TWENTY', 'SIXTYEIGHT', 'ONE-HUNDRED', 'SEVEN',
...      'FIVE', 'NINE', 'ONE', 'ZERO', 'ELEVEN', 'TWO-HUNDRED',
...      'TWENTY-EIGHT', 'FOUR', 'TWELVE'])
>>> set(['ONE', 'THREE', 'TWO', 'EIGHT', 'ONE-HUNDRED']) <= setb
False
>>> set(['ONE', 'ONE-HUNDRED']) <= setb  # some elements all in b
True
>>> setb <= setb  # set b is of course a subset of itself
True
```

If you need to discover matching keys, use [*dictionary views*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects); these act like sets too:

```
all(set(A[k]) <= set(B[k]) for k in A.viewkeys() & B.viewkeys())
```

For Python 3, use `A.keys()` and `B.keys()`; there the implementation for `dict.viewkeys()` has replaced the old Python 2 `dict.keys()` list.

`foo & bar` produces the intersection of the two dictionaries -- all keys they have in common:

```
>>> A = {'Key1': ['ONE', 'THREE', 'TWO', 'EIGHT', 'ONE-HUNDRED'],
...      'Key2': ['THREE', 'EIGHT', 'FORTYSEVEN', 'TWO'],
...      'Key3': ['ONE-HUNDRED', 'SEVEN', 'NINE', 'ONE']
...     }
>>> B = {'Key1': ['TWENTY', 'SIXTYEIGHT', 'ONE-HUNDRED', 'SEVEN',
...      'FIVE', 'NINE', 'ONE', 'ZERO', 'ELEVEN', 'TWO-HUNDRED',
...      'TWENTY-EIGHT', 'FOUR', 'TWELVE']
... }
>>> A.viewkeys() & B.viewkeys()
set(['Key1'])
```

By using `all()` you get to test if the values for all matching keys are subsets:

```
>>> all(set(A[k]) <= set(B[k]) for k in A.viewkeys() & B.viewkeys())
False
>>> A['Key1'] = ['ONE', 'ONE-HUNDRED']
>>> all(set(A[k]) <= set(B[k]) for k in A.viewkeys() & B.viewkeys())
True
```

If you need to make a lot of these tests, consider converting your dictionary values to sets permanently.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get a return of True if all, and just not any, values of Key1 in A exist in B, without B having the exact amount of values?

For this specific question I would use:

```
all([value in B['Key1'] for value in A['Key1']])
```

Using your initial dicts:

```
>>> A = {'Key1': ['ONE', 'THREE', 'TWO', 'EIGHT', 'ONE-HUNDRED'],
         'Key2': ['THREE', 'EIGHT', 'FORTYSEVEN', 'TWO'],
         'Key3': ['ONE-HUNDRED', 'SEVEN', 'NINE', 'ONE']}

>>> B = {'Key1': ['TWENTY', 'SIXTYEIGHT', 'ONE-HUNDRED', 'SEVEN', 
                  'FIVE', 'NINE', 'ONE', 'ZERO', 'ELEVEN', 'TWO-HUNDRED',
                  'TWENTY-EIGHT', 'FOUR', 'TWELVE']}

>>> all([value in B['Key1'] for value in A['Key1']])
False
```

Now adding in the keys that B is missing from A:

```
>>> A = {'Key1': ['ONE', 'THREE', 'TWO', 'EIGHT', 'ONE-HUNDRED'],
         'Key2': ['THREE', 'EIGHT', 'FORTYSEVEN', 'TWO'],
         'Key3': ['ONE-HUNDRED', 'SEVEN', 'NINE', 'ONE']}

>>> B = {'Key1': ['THREE', 'EIGHT', 'TWENTY', 'SIXTYEIGHT',
                  'ONE-HUNDRED', 'SEVEN', 'FIVE', 'NINE', 
                  'ONE', 'ZERO', 'ELEVEN', 'TWO-HUNDRED',
                  'TWENTY-EIGHT', 'FOUR', 'TWELVE', 'TWO']}
>>> all([value in B['Key1'] for value in A['Key1']])
True
```

Answer (score -1):

If i understand correctly you require key having all values in B['Key1']. Following code should work for you.

```
A = {'Key1': ['ONE', 'THREE', 'TWO', 'EIGHT', 'ONE-HUNDRED'],
     'Key2': ['THREE', 'EIGHT', 'FORTYSEVEN', 'TWO'],
     'Key3': ['ONE-HUNDRED', 'SEVEN', 'NINE', 'ONE']
    }

B = {'Key1': ['TWENTY', 'SIXTYEIGHT', 'ONE-HUNDRED', 'SEVEN', 
     'FIVE', 'NINE', 'ONE', 'ZERO', 'ELEVEN', 'TWO-HUNDRED',
     'TWENTY-EIGHT', 'FOUR', 'TWELVE']
}
def chk_val(a,b):
    for key in a:
        print("%s = %s"%(key,set(A[key]) <= set(B['Key1'])))

chk_val(A,B)
```

the o/p will be

Key1 = False

Key2 = False

Key3 = True